# HTML lists not redering correctly in report textbox

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a text box that I have turned on HTML rendering for.  This is the text it should render (formatting added for readability)

```
<P>This is the Description Field.</P> 
<OL> 
    <LI>First List Item</LI> 
    <LI>Second List Item</LI> 
    <LI>Last List Item</LI>
</OL> 
<P>Not in the list</P>
```

I am expecting to see something like this in my report:

```
This is the Description Field.
```

`1. First List Item
  2. Second List Item
  3. Last List Item

Not in the list<\pre>`

But I am getting this:

> > This is the Description Field.
> >     First List Item
> >     Second List Item
> >     Last List Item
> >     Not in the list

The [docs say that `<LI>` and `<OL>` and `<P>` are supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645967.aspx)... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can only have the one placeholder in your text box for the HTML to render correctly.

I had two placeholders in the textbox.  One to say "Description: " and one to show the description.  When I removed the first it started working.